# Extracting Facebook Posts & Comments with BeautifulSoup & Requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I was trying to Scrape comments but i am getting error saying Invalid URL 'email'. Can anyone tell me why this code is not working : here u can see the code :https://repl.it/repls/BleakShorttermFormats

Comment: Please share all relevant information in the post itself.

Comment: @AMC as  the code is long getting the code from the link will be easy

Comment: @DaviLeo Sorry, that's not how Stack Overflow works. We expect you to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the problem. Nobody will offer help if they have to trawl through your code on external sites.